# If $A\subset X$ is path connected, then $H_0(A)\to H_0(X)$ is injective.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I wonder if the following is true

> Let $X$ be a path-connected space and $A\subset X$ be a path-connected subspace. Then, $H_0(A)\to H_0(X)$ is injective.

I've seen that $H_0(A)\to H_0(X)$ is injective and $A\subset X$ is path connected subspace is an equivalnet statement. Forward direction is easy. The problem is the reverse direction. How can I show? Only thing thing to show is the case when $\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z$ is a zero map. But I can't find the contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is true, in fact it is an isomorphism. Since $H_{0}$ is generated by the class of a point on both sides, and a point clearly goes to a point, hence the map is an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You mean the zero map can't be happen.

Comment: yes, because a generator of $H_{0}(A)$ is mapped to a generator of $H_{0}(X)$